# Where are iOS 5 Camera Roll folders stored when synced with Windows?

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows, ios, camera

iOS 5 has introduced the ability to create folders in the image library, and copy pictures from the camera roll to these folders.

When synced on a PC (on Windows 7), where are those pictures stored? How can they be managed on the computer?

I'd like to find them to be able to save them, and add/remove some pictures from those folders.

I know the way to add "hard" folders to the image library from the PC, but those can't be managed on the iPhone.

Comment: Why the rollback?

Comment: @Loïc Wolff : Because it's about ios5, and if you delete this from the title, it won't be visible when searching that question by google. That would confuse people searching that for ios4. And adding "ios" "5" into google does not help. and typing "ios-5" is not natural. etc...

Comment: Adding tags in front of the title is not how it's done here, you can add "on iOS 5" somewhere in your title (don't worry about Google, this site is practically indexed in real time)

Comment: @Oliver Tags in Titles are disallowed on the SE network, the tags are indexed by google. However I have edited the title to include iOS 5.

Comment: @Diago : Does not matter if the tags are indexed or not by google. The problem is about what the user may type for its google request : iOS5, iOS 5, iOS-5, iOS5.0, ...  That MUST be in the title, as you did.

Answer (score 1):

The sync image location would be the same as the one you have selected as your Sync folder via iTunes Photo sync. I have also found a less complicated - drag/drop method for a two-way [iPhone photo transfer](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3181-an-alternative-to-itunes-for-managing-your-photos-or-music) between your device and the PC. It is less of a hassle since you can manage your iPhone photos, add and move them around and sync them to your PC directly from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Mine get put into my pictures folder in the same place you iPhone puts them when it asked when y plug iPhone in it should ask do you  take pictures off because computer thinks my iPhone is a camera so it ask to download photos